# Use JavaScript or JQuery inside a <c:if> Statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstl

I need to make the following work, does anybody have an idea how:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function raceChecked(raceID){
    return $('#raceCheck_'+raceID).attr('checked');
}
</script>
<div>
    <c:forEach items="${raceEvent.raceList}" var="race">
    <div><input type="checkbox" value="${race.id}" checked="checked" onClick="refreshPage()"/><c:out value="${race.name}"/></div>
    </c:forEach>
</div>  
<c:if test="raceChecked(${race.id})">
  <!--SHOW RACE -->
</c:if>
```

The interesting part is the last `<c:if test="raceChecked(${race.id})">`
This doesn't work, because he does not call the JavaScript function!

But how can I make this work?
I want the user to decide with the checkboxes which race is shown. These races cannot be hidden using JQuery. They must not be shown in the Source Code.

Somebody an idea?

Comment: I'm guessing this is JSP, and I don't think you can include javascript for client interaction without it showing up in the source. Also some script tags and document.ready would help.

Comment: It's not the way to do so. JSTL doesn't allow you to call a Javascript function from the `test` condition of `<c:if></c:if>`. It can just evaluate EL expressions. Why don't you use server-side mechanisms like beans, custom tags etc instead?

Comment: i just forgot to copy the script tag... :)
The real source code is 300 lines long. But this is the important part!

Comment: @Lion
Unfortunately that doesn't work. The JavaServlet gives me a huge map with information, opened inside an JQuery Dialog, which cannot be reloaded. The user has to have the possibility to check dynamically which race he want to see. I am doing a calculation of all shown races, so I can't just hide these races.
Isn't there a possibilty to check inside the ´test` condition, what checkbox is checked?

Answer (score 0):

JSTL is executed on the server but javascript on the client.
You could use `<body onload="raceChecked(${race.id})">` if you need to check what to display on loading.